# BackButton event affects other pages in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

In my PhoneGap android app, in my Index.html page in **OnDeviceReady()** method I have added the following function for backbutton event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
          var sPath=window.location.pathname;
          var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          if(sPage == "index.html"){
                e.preventDefault();
                // My action
                return false;

            } else {
                return true;
            }
    }, false);
```

**Problem Facing:**
In my HomePage(Index.html) its working fine. If i press back button it gets closed.
But in all other pages (Page1.html,Page2.html,Page3.html,Page4.html) i havn't created backbutton event listener but nothing happens when i press back key.

Comment: how are you moving from homepage to another page ?

Comment: from a button click event using the code "window.location = "page1.html";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by adding the following javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e) {
          var sPath=window.location.pathname;
          var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          if(sPage == "index.html"){
                e.preventDefault();
//  Method to close Phonegap application
                 navigator.app.exitApp();


                } else {
   // Method to go back to previous page 
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
        }, false);
```

Alternate approach which definitely works but uses two JavaScript files...

I have used the following code for pages other than index.html :

```
// Wait for Cordova to load

     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       // Cordova is ready

    function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.app.backHistory();
    return false;
}, true);

        }
```

And on Home page you can add  navigator.app.exitApp(); and remove navigator.app.backHistory();

Already answered here:
[PhoneGap - android exit on backbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338337/phonegap-android-exit-on-backbutton)

Comment: sjmach, thanks for your help. The second code works fine but the drawback is if i have 10 html files for 10 pages i need ti implement the listener for all 10 pages. I wonder why the back button event is not working in other pages while implementing on Home page!!!!!!