# How to quit (exit) cordova (android) application when you click on the back button from Inappbrowser?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, back-button

I'm developing an android application using cordova , I want to quit the application when i click on the back button knowing that i'm using Inappbrowser, could someone help me??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338337/phonegap-android-exit-on-backbutton

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


if (navigator.userAgent.match("Android"))
{
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, true);
}
function onBackKeyDown(e) 
{navigator.app.exitApp();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the android life cycle (how apps are managed, cached etc.) it is not recommended to close apps. The user should just minimize it. You can stop all background-threads using onPause() method, if you have any.

By force-closing you will drain some battery, because android has to reload everything instead of loading a cached version.